# How to access a website database?

Tags: 7

Firstly I'm extreamly new to drupal and right now I was given a task to edit a currently online published website. The old designer didn't left me with any idea but from what I was told, the website uses Drupal to operate. I'm more to the classical way of building a website, for example: I create the scripts and upload it to a server and the server published it online. So how do I acess the website's database to make all the necessary changes to the scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you don't generally access the database in Drupal.  Drupal serves as an intermediary between you and the database, and if you access the database directly more than likely you are going to cause yourself many problems in the long run, especially in the beginning when you're not very familiar with Drupal.

For more, see [Understanding Drupal](http://drupal.org/documentation/understand) and the [Structure Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/structure) on Drupal.org.

Comment: Hello!

Thank you for the reply and thank you for the useful links on Drupal. I'll navigate myself around Drupal and understand more about the structure.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you do not want to access the database without using Drupals functions to do so.  With that being said you can create modules that will do that work for you.  This can cause issues if you try to access and manipulate data from the database without using drupal functions to do it for youu.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. Any useful link for me to learn more about Drupal?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Drupal world! :D

First what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to update the Drupal code? Before touching prod make sure you have a [backup](http://drupal.org/node/839648) of the latest db and code. You must be aware of the golden rule "[don't hack the core](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core)". Drupal uses [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal)(hook) in extending Drupal functionality.

It's not a good practice to do the development directly on live. If you want to update database in live for some reason, use [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) and run in live once deploy.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hello!

Firstly, thank you for the warm welcome! :)
Secondly, what I'm trying to achieve is more to like editing a published website. Through my experience, web designing is like I'll do the scripts, I'll upload it to a server/host and the server/host will do the publishing for me. So generally for me to do any editing, I'll just access my database in the server. So more likely right now I would like to learn how do I access this 'database' through Drupal.

Thank you for the reply! :)